# C# .Net 3.5 Remove Event added to PrintDialog before add new event

Tags: c#, printdialog

When I click button "Print" my form

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog.Document.PrintPage += (pSender, pE) => PrintEvent(pSender, pE, PrintInfo);
    PrintDialog.Document.Print();
}
```

`PrintDialog` is global variable type `System.windows.forms.PrintDialog`. When I click button "Print" at second time, I want remove PrintEvent added at the first time clicked button before add new PrintEvent. How can I do?

Comment: You are just doing it wrong, the event needs to be subscribed when you assign the Document property.  Just once, almost always in the constructor of your Form class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it, you must convert lambda to method:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog.Document.PrintPage -= Print;
    PrintDialog.Document.PrintPage += Print;
    PrintDialog.Document.Print();
}

void Print(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
(
    //pass info
    PrintEvent(sender, e, PrintInfo)
)
```